# Assign user to group in Azure Active Directory using Microsoft Graph PHP SDK

Tags: php, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting various error messages depending on various attempted implementations to achieve the mentioned issue. Here is what I tried to do:

1. Assign group on user creation

   ```
   //Get group object

   $group = $graph->createRequest('GET', "/groups/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx")
         ->setReturnType(Model\Group::class)
         ->execute();

   $newUser = new Model\User();
   $newUser->setGivenName($firstName);
   $newUser->setSurname($surname);
   $newUser->setUserPrincipalName($userPrincipalName.'@xxxxxx.com');
   // $newUser->setUserType($userType);
   // $newUser->setMySite($website);
   $newUser->setPasswordProfile(["forceChangePasswordNextSignIn" => false,'password' => $pwd]);
   $newUser->setDisplayName($firstName.' '.$surname);
   $newUser->setMailNickname($firstName.$surname);
   $newUser->setMemberOf([$group]);
   $newUser->setAccountEnabled(true);

   $user = $graph->createRequest($action, "/users")
         ->attachBody($newUser)
         ->setReturnType(Model\User::class)
         ->execute();
   ```
2. Assign membership through group object

   ```
   //we get $user object from the last line above     
   $grp = $graph->createRequest('POST', "/groups/xxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx/members/\$ref")
         ->attachBody(["@odata.id" => $graph->$_baseUrl.'/'.$graph->$_apiVersion.'/users/'.$user->id])
         ->setReturnType(Model\Group::class)
         ->execute();
   ```

None of the above strategies work. I'd really appreciate pointers to where I am going wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are the "various error messages" you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if your first approach (referencing the group as part of `memberOf` when creating the user) is supported.

You second approach has a couple issues:

1. By using `$graph->$_baseUrl` and `$graph->$_apiVersion`, you are attempting to reference private properties of `$graph`, which you cannot do (because they're private). See the PHP documentation for more information on [visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php).
2. You are attempting to reference the user's `id` attribute with `$user->id`. This would work only if `$user` had a public property named `id` (which it doesn't). Instead, you need to use the getter for the `id`: `$user->getId()`.

An approach that works is the following (which is a slight variation of your second attempt):

```
// Add $user as a member of $group
$newMemberRef = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/' . $user->getId();
$groupMembersRef = '/groups/' . $group->getId() . '/members/$ref';
$response = $graph->createRequest('POST', $groupMembersRef)
            ->attachBody(['@odata.id' => $newMemberRef])
            ->execute();
```

(Note how in this case we're referencing a `user` object, though you could also reference a `group` object, or (more generically) a `directoryObject` object.)

Comment: All along I though the problem was with the SDK.